# Можно ли создавать мобильные приложения на C или C++?

Tags: android, c++, c, ios, app

Можно ли создавать мобильные приложения на C/C++? Будут ли они корректно работать и можно ли из cpp-файлов создать apk и ipa?

Comment: Можно, много игрушек требовательных написаны на С/C++. Посмотрите в сторону https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x, пишем на плюсах, собираем под Win/Linux/Android/iOS/Mac.

Comment: Я хочу разрабатывать не игры, а мобильные приложения. Но всё равно спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не прибегая к коду Java не выйдет. Android NDK позволит писать на С++ только некоторые части приложения, например библиотеки. Там прям на главной странице написано: The Android NDK is a toolset that lets you implement parts of your app using native-code languages such as C and C++. For certain types of apps, this can help you reuse code libraries written in those languages.

PS:ответ не мой,нашел [здесь](https://qna.habr.com/q/333356)

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!